# Can't include wijmo-angular in GruntJS (with Karma Runner)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner, wijmo

When running 'grunt test', I get the famous Script Error. However it does not come from RequireJS, but from the fact that I'm trying to include the wijmo-angularjs script:
http://cdn.wijmo.com/interop/angular.wijmo.3.20131.7.js
Unfortunately there's not stacktrace or whatsoever.

Has anyone tackled this issue?

Here's my karma config script, which will fail with any Yeoman/Grunt/Karma project:

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath : '',

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files : [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js',
  'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js',
  'http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.all.2.3.9.js',
  'http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.3.9.js',
  'http://cdn.wijmo.com/interop/angular.wijmo.3.20131.7.js',
  'app/scripts/*.coffee',
  'app/scripts/**/*.coffee',
  'test/mock/**/*.coffee',
  'test/spec/**/*.coffee'
],

// list of files to exclude
exclude : [],

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: dots || progress || growl
reporters : ['progress'],

// web server port
port : 8080,

// cli runner port
runnerPort : 9100,

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors : true,

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel : LOG_INFO,

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch : false,

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers : ['Chrome'],

// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout : 5000,

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun : false,

});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when using the latest version of that problematic script:
http://cdn.wijmo.com/interop/angular.wijmo.3.20132.9.js